# Can the entropy of a random variable with countably many outcomes be infinite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, information-theory, entropy

Consider a random variable $X$ taking values over $\mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathbb{P}(X = i) = p_i$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$. The entropy of $X$ is defined by
$$H(X) = \sum_i -p_i \log p_i.$$
Is it possible for $H(X)$ to be infinite?

Comment: Googling "random variable infinite entropy" gives [this](http://j.ee.washington.edu/~bilmes/classes/ee514a_winter_2012/hw2-solns.pdf) example.

Comment: @David: You could turn that into a full answer by quoting the distribution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it can.

In [this](http://j.ee.washington.edu/~bilmes/classes/ee514a_winter_2012/hw2-solns.pdf) pdf, it is shown that the following random variable $X$ has infinite entropy:

Let $X$ take the values $2,3,\ldots$ and define $$p_n={1\over A n\log^2_2 n},\ \ \ n\ge2,$$ where $A = \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n\log^2_2 n}$ ($A$ is a convergent sum by the Integral Test). Then $X$ with the probability mass function $P[X=n]=p_n$, $n\ge 2$, has infinite entropy.

For completeness, I'll reproduce the argument contained in the link above  that $H(X)=\infty$ here:

We have 
$$\eqalign{
H(X)&=-\sum_{n=2} p_n \log_2 p_n   \cr
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\bigl( -\log_2(p_n)\bigr) p_n\cr
&= \sum_{n=2}{\log_2( An \log_2^2 n  )\over A n\log_2^2 n}   \cr
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty {{\log_2 A+\log_2 n +2\log_2(\log_2 n))}\over A n \log_2^2 n}\cr
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\biggl[\ \color{maroon}{\log_2 A\over A n\log_2^2 n}+\color{darkgreen}{1\over A n\log_2 n}+\color{darkblue}{2\log_2(\log_2 n)) \over A n\log_2^2 n}\    \biggr].\cr
}
$$

Now
$$
\color{maroon}{
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty {\log_2 A\over A n\log_2^2 n}}
={\log_2 A\over A}
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty {1\over  n\log_2^2 n} ={\log_2 A\over A}\cdot A=\log_2 A.
$$

and 
$$
\color{darkblue}{
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty {2\log_2(\log_2 n)\over A n\log_2^2 n}}
$$
is a sum consisting of nonnegative terms.

It will  follow that $H(X)=\infty$, if we can show that the sum 
$$
\color{darkgreen}{\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over An\log_2 n}} 
$$
diverges to $\infty$.  But, this follows easily from the Integral Test.

(From the Integral Test, it follows that $\int_2^\infty {dx\over x\log_2^p x}$
converges if and only if $p>1$.)

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if there are sufficient (or even necessary and sufficient) conditions for entropy to be finite.

Comment: @VSJ I knew there is a sufficient condition, but the necessary condition is really nowhere that I know of, I post this question on MO. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/264401/a-necessary-condition-for-differential-entropy-to-be-finite

Comment: Don't you need to also show that the p_n add up to 1?

Comment: @PyRulez The presence of the factor $A$ in the definition of $p_n$ insures that.

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh yeah, I see now.

Answer (score 27):

Consider the independent variables $ X_1, X_2 , X_3 \cdots$, where $X_k$ have non overlapping discrete uniform distributions over $2^k$ values: $X_1 \sim U[2\ldotp\ldotp3]$, $X_2\sim  U[4\ldotp\ldotp7]$, $X_3 \sim  U[8\ldotp\ldotp15]$, etc. The respective entropies are $H(X_k) = k$ bits.

Now, we pick one of the $X_k$ according to some probability mass function $m_k$ ($\sum_{k=1}^\infty m_k=1)$. That is,
$Y =X_M$ where $P(M=k)=m_k$. This is known as a mixture, with mixing distribution $m_k$, and the resulting entropy (because the components do not overlap) is

$$\begin{array}{}
H(Y)&=&H(M)+m_1  H(X_1)+ m_2 H(X_2) + m_3 H(X_3) +\cdots \\
&=& H(M) + m_1  + 2 \, m_2 + 3 \, m_3 \cdots \\&=& H(M) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \, k \, m_k  \\&=& H(M) + E(M)
\end{array}$$

Hence, by chosing any mixing distribution $m_k$ with infinite mean ($E(M)=\sum k \, m_k=+\infty$), we attain infinite entropy. For example: $m_k=A/k^2$ (the example in David's answer essentially corresponds to this choice). Or, [similarly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/366864/2546), $m_k = \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{1}{k^2+k}$