# Infinite entropy

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I am learning about entropy, and am slightly confused by an exercise in a book. It asks if there exists a discrete random variable $X$ with distribution such that $H(X)=\infty$. My intuition is that there is not, as the set is always countable as it is a discrete random variable, and the probability is less than one, and the definition for entropy is $$H(X)=-\sum_{x\in{X}}P(X=x)log(P(X=x))$$
Any help understanding this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This question is answered here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279304/can-the-entropy-of-a-random-variable-with-countably-many-outcomes-be-infinite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the entropy of a random variable with countably many outcomes be infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279304/can-the-entropy-of-a-random-variable-with-countably-many-outcomes-be-infinite)