# Best way to play 20 questions

Tags: statistical-inference, game-theory, information-theory, entropy

### Background

You and I are going to play a game. To start off with I play a measurable function $f_1$ and you respond with a real number $y_1$ (possibly infinite). We repeat this some fixed number $N$ of times, to obtain a collection $\{(f_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$. Define

$\Gamma=\{\mu: \mu $ is a probability measure, and $\int f_i(x)d\mu(x)=y_i \forall i\}$

(We'll assume that $\Gamma$ is not empty, meaning you cannot give inconsistent answers. For example, if I play $f_1(x)=x^2$, then you could not play $y_1=-1$).

Next, I play a measure $P$ which must satisfy $P\in \Gamma$. You then play a measure $Q\in \Gamma$. The game is scored such that your reward is equal to $H(Q|P)$ (the cross entropy) while my reward is equal to $-H(Q|P)$. In other words, I am rewarded to the extent that I can guess your distribution, while you are rewarded to the extent that you can foil my guess.

What should my strategy be for playing this game?

### Motivation

This game can be considered as a general model of scientist designing experiments (the functions $f_i$) and using the results of those experiments to develop a theory (the measure $P$). The other player is a stand-in for "Nature", which we assume acts against us at every turn.

Further, the game is a generalization of the setting considered by Grunwald and Dawid [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410076.pdf). They consider what amounts to a special case of this game in which the set $\Gamma$ is assumed to be specified ahead of time (so each participant only specifies their distribution). Very interestingly, they show that in this case the optimal strategy is to play the distribution $\text{arg max}_{P\in\Gamma} H(P)$, where $H$ denotes Shannon entropy. This amounts to a passive model of scientific inference, in which the scientist has access only to observational data in the forms of constraints $\int f_i(x)d\mu(x)=y_i$, but has no control over what the actual functions $f_i$ are. Thus I am interested in what would happen if their setting is extended to an "active" one, in which the scientist can control which statistics $f_i$ to measure in the first place.

Comment: I'm having trouble with that $\Gamma$ guy. What you propose is that given the $f_{i}$s one associates $y_{i}$s but only in such a way that there exists some probability measure $\gamma\in\Gamma$. Now why is it clear in the first place, that $\Gamma$ must contain also other measures than $\gamma$, which it should, since otherwise part two of your game becomes rather boring.

Comment: @Tobsn It's certainly possible that $\Gamma$ could be a singleton set. For example, consider the sequence of moves $f_1(x)=x, y_1=1, f_2(x)=x^2, y_2=1$. Then all distributions except a delta at 1 are ruled out. However, from the second player's perspective, playing $y_2=1$ would be a bad move, exactly because it leaves only one possible distribution. So if the second player is playing optimally then we should expect that $\Gamma$ will not be a singleton.

Answer (score 4):

I will consider the case where all distributions are supported on a fixed finite set $\{1,2,\dots, M\}$. Hopefully someone will see how to extend to the continuous case.

*All strategies for Player 1 are equivalent. Moreover, the eventual payoff does not depend on the number of questions asked.*

In retrospect, this is maybe not surprising in light of the No Free Lunch theorem. To see it directly, first note that the optimal move for Player 1, conditional on any history $\{(f_i,y_i)\}$ is to play $P_{f,p}:=argmax_{P\in \Gamma_{\{(f_i,y_i)\}}} H(P)$. (This is also true when $N=0$). This is a consequence of the result of Grunwald/Dawid mentioned in the question. By a standard argument involving Lagrange multipliers, the distribution takes the form

$$P_{f,p}(x)=e^{\sum_i \lambda_i f_i(x)-A(\lambda)}$$

where $\lambda_i$ are chosen to satisfy the constraints $\sum_x f_i(x) P_{f,p}(x)=y_i$ and $A(\lambda)$ is chosen so that the total probability mass sums to 1.

Now let $Q\in \Gamma_{(f,p)}$. By the definition of cross entropy we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
H(Q|P_{f,y})&=&-\sum_x Q(x)\log P_{f,y}(x)\\
&=&-\sum_x Q(x) \left(\sum_i \lambda_i f_i(x)-A(\lambda)\right)\\
&=&-\sum_i \lambda_i \sum_x f_i(x)Q(x)+A(\lambda)\\
& = & -\sum_i \lambda_i y_i+A(\lambda)
\end{eqnarray*}

(In the last equality, we used the assumption that $Q\in \Gamma_{(f,y)}$). So in fact the cross entropy does not depend on $Q$, and is always equal to $H(P_{f,y})$. Said another way, the payoff to Player 2, conditional on the moves $\{(f_i,y_i)\}$ is equal to $H(P_{f,y})$.

The best case scenario for Player 2 would be if $P_{f,y}$ is the uniform distribution $Unif_M$ (since this has the highest entropy among all distributions on $\{1,2,\dots, M\}$). Player 2 can achieve this by following the strategy of playing $y_i=\sum_x f_i(x)/M$ in response to any move $f_i$ made by Player 1. It is easy to see that if $y_i$ are defined in this way, then $Unif_M\in \Gamma_{(f,y)}$, no matter what the functions $f_i$ are, which implies that $Unif_M=P_{f,y}$.

So no matter which or how many functions Player 1 plays, Player 2 can always force Player 1 to play $Unif_M$, for a resulting score of $log M$.

**Unbounded Case**

Here we assume that the distributions are supported on a non-compact set, either the integers or the real line. In this case, there exist distributions that have infinite entropy ([Can the entropy of a random variable with countably many outcomes be infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279304/can-the-entropy-of-a-random-variable-with-countably-many-outcomes-be-infinite)). Now in general $H(Q|P)\ge H(Q)$, since KL divergence is always non-negative. This means that, as long as there is some distribution in $\Gamma$ that has infinite entropy, Player 2 can play that distribution, and thus obtain infinite reward. But making sure that $\Gamma$ contains such a distribution is easy, since Player 2 can just choose some distribution $Q$ with infinite entropy ahead of time, and then respond to any function $f_i$ with $y_i=E_{x\sim Q}f_i(x)$. So the game as stated is degenerate in this case.

Comment: I really enjoyed reading that paper. Let me see if I can assist you here.